# trying to get jquery countdown to work but its not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

html file:

```
    // <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"    
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Coming Soon</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link href="tools/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="tools/jquery.countdown.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="tools/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="tools/jquery.countdown.js"></script>
    <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="tools/bg.js"></script> -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
var austDay = new Date();
austDay = new Date(2013, 10, 18, 12, 00);
$('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: austDay});
$('#year').text(austDay.getFullYear());
    });

    $(function(){
    $('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();
    setInterval(function(){
      $('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut(3000)
     .next('img').fadeIn(3000)
     .end().appendTo('.fadein');}, 
      3000); // change this to change the transition timing
  });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="shim"></div>
    <div class="fadein">
    <img src="images/photo1.jpg">
    <img src="images/photo2.jpg">
<img src="images/photo3.jpg">
<img src="images/photo4.jpg">
<img src="images/photo5.jpg">
    </div>
    <div id="content">
    <div class="logo"><h1>Sva Spa and Salon</span></h1></div>   
<div class="right_side">
    <div class="right_content">
        <h2>Watch For Our Brand New Website</h2>
        <div id="defaultCountdown"></div>
        <form class="email" action="">
            <input class="get_notified" type="text"     
    onfocus="if(this.value=='Provide EMAIL for Reminder') this.value='';"        
    onblur="if(this.value=='' || this.value==' ') this.value='Provide EMAIL for   
    Reminder';"     
    value="Provide EMAIL for Reminder"/>
            <input type="button" class="go" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

I get images rotating as well as the text of the counter coming up but it only decreases when I refresh the page. Also I wanted to add a php code for the submit button to send the email address to another email address how can I do this? Please help im stuck....

Comment: Simplify your code post the part related with your iusse not the whole page (the part relate with the includes of js or css really doen't have any value with the problem (be consice) , 2.-indent your code.

Comment: @ Rafael Hi Rafael, Im not sure what the issue is since the timer is showing it only goes down when I hit the refresh button. I thought I did indent y code. Any help you can give me would be much appreciated. do you want the js files also?

Answer (score 0):

Three things:

1. There is nothing with id `year`, this is intentional?
2. Countdown [should working good](http://jsfiddle.net/GQvAP/), but it's your job to debug rest of your code
3. Put your code inside [.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function

code:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   //your code
 });
```

Comment: @ yarl thanks! it is working. Can i get some help on the PHP script for getting the go button to submit?

Comment: @ rafael whats weird is it works on macbook pro and ipad but not on my laptop? any ideas?

Comment: @user2895617 what version jQuery are you using and which browser and version are you using in your Windows PC

Comment: @ Rafael, dw and thank you I figured it out. I was querying var date when I should have just taken the existing date. Thank you though